# UIDatepicker slows loading in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using UIDatepicker in my Tableview .I have embed UIDatepicker in my Tableviewcell storyboard. So basically it is a form which may have multiple date pickers. So I use hide/show logic. It was working fine when I use Datepicker with UIToolbar , but I want to use UIDatepicker (non-programmatic way), but when I use this, loading of viewcontroller becomes slow. How to fix this ? Why is this happening? I am using Swift 4.

This is my datepicker
[my UIDatepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvf2b.png)

Comment: You have not provided and useful details for anyone to help you. You need to [edit] your question and post relevant code or details about what exactly you are doing to setup the date picker.

Answer (score -1):

Initialise A UIDatePicker.

```
var birthPicker = UIDatePicker()
```

//add target on birthPicker for getting Date.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.birthPicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    self.birthPicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}
```

// Get Date from UIDatePicker on scrolling.

```
 @objc func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateStyle = .long

    birthDateField.text = timeFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```

Comment: Still there is slowness in loading the viewcontroller